Airflow task_group with list from previous task
Based on the following answer to a similar question, I'm trying to create an airflow task_group based of an output from a previous task.
More precisely, my first task uses the ExecuteSQLQueryOperator which returns a list. And I want to use this list to map it to a task group. However I always end up with a TypeError: 'XComArg' object is not iterable.
I don't know how to write a reproducible example with the sql operator, but I can at least write some pseudo code:
from airflow.decorators import dag, task_group
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

@dag()
def my_dag():
    get_list = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id='get_list',
        conn_id=pg_conn_id,
        database=db_name,
        sql='select column from table',
    )

    @task_group()
    def map_list_to_task(l: list):
        return list(map(my_task, l))

    def my_task(element):
        # define and return a task
        return DummyOperator()


    map_list_to_task(get_list.output)

dag = my_dag()

By simply replacing get_list.output by a true list on the last line, it works. But I need to make it work with the result from the previous task get_list. Any help would be much appreciated!

Could you please provide some context about your next steps for using the "l" variable? The issue is that the task group method parameters are not converted into basic Python types, unlike when using them under a method with the @task decorator

I managed to find a solution which satisfies my needs by using danamic-task-mapping.
from airflow.decorators import dag, task_group
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

@dag()
def my_dag():
    get_list = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id='get_list',
        conn_id=pg_conn_id,
        database=db_name,
        sql='select column from table',
    )

    @task
    def my_task(element):
        # do something with element
        result = element
        return result


    my_task.expand(element=get_list)

dag = my_dag()

